# How to convert string to NSDate in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am geting below date from the server now I want to convert string to date.

Wed, 08 Jun 2011 11:58 pm EDT

But I cant success please give me advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 89, accepted):

### [How-To: Convert a string to NSDate](http://blog.evandavey.com/2008/12/how-to-convert-a-string-to-nsdate.html)

In ***Objective-C***, you commonly nead to convert a string to an `NSDate` object.  A simple way to do this is using the NSDateFormatter object.  It provides the dateFromString method which converts a string into an NSDate object.  You do, however, need to tell `NSDateFormatter` the format the date will be in.  See below example:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: myDateAsAStringValue];
```

And read about [***EDT – Eastern Daylight Time***](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/edt.html) I think it would be better you change EDT to -0004.

Comment: Note, you should use _HH_ instead of _hh_, like this `[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];`, otherwise in 24-hour format `dateFromString:` sometimes returns `nil`

Comment: ProTip: If you're parsing lots of data, be sure to recycle your date formatter as they're expensive to create every time.

Comment: This gives me nill?? any idea why?

Answer (score 17):

ViTo basically answers this, but the precise format you're looking at for the string you are concerned with is:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM y hh:mm a zzz"];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Wed, 08 Jun 2011 11:58 pm EDT"]);
```

Take a look at [the date format patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns). I add this because it wasn't immediately obvious where to find a description of the pattern.

Comment: This giving me nill? any idea why? @ben

Comment: @Vijay_07 Check for typos? Still works fine for me 4.5 years later.