# convert date string to NSDate in objective c/iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this string ----> Sun, 16 Dec 2012 15:30:22 +0000

I want to convert it to NSDate. I have tried the below code but it is giving me null

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

date = [df dateFromString: @"Sun, 16 Dec 2012 15:30:22 +0000"];

NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

I am not getting the issue ?

Any guidance plz

Comment: 1) You don't need to `alloc/init` `date` before using it. The object you create on that line will be leaked (in MRC) or immediately discarded (in ARC.) 2) Does your date look *anything* like "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a" would imply it should?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert string to NSDate in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288371/how-to-convert-string-to-nsdate-in-iphone)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `dateFormat` of the formatter needs to match the format of the string you are providing it with.

Therefore something like this should work

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ";

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter dateFromString:@"Fri, 18 Jan 2013 15:30:22 +0000"]);
```

To look up what the specifiers actually mean check [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [df setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy"];

    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    date = [df dateFromString: @"Sun, 16 Dec 2012"];

    NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

Hope it helps you..

EDIT :-

For your string

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [df setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];

    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    date = [df dateFromString: @"Sun, 16 Dec 2012 15:30:22 +0000"];

    NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

Comment: Thanks Prateek its working now, but when I want to convert this string "Sun, 16 Dec 2012 15:30:22 +0000" to NSDate, it again gives me null

Comment: Oh! you accepted somebody else answer, I posted answer first :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get NSDate from String

```
- (NSDate*) dateFromString:(NSString*)aStr
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
    //[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    NSLog(@"%@", aStr);
    NSDate   *aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:aStr];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return aDate;
}
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: Ya u r right, missed that. my fault.
I have edited it in correct format