# Convert date to string with different date format ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I search some stack quentions for converting string to date and that's working fine, but i convert my string date to NSDate than it's return me nil. Here is my code :

```
   NSString *dateStr = @"2016-07-29 09:05";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

I want to convert this date to `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ` this formate.

What's problem here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert date string to NSDate in objective c/iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398604/convert-date-string-to-nsdate-in-objective-c-ios)

Comment: question s good what output you expected

Comment: my date is not match with my format, but that format what i want, cann't he take 00 in milisecond ?

Comment: Set the dateFormat to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" when you successfully converted the string to nsdate, you can change the dateFormat to yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Comment: The date string doesn't match the formatting string.

Comment: Useful for date formats http://nsdateformatter.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do like

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2016-07-29 09:05";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// set the date format related to what the string already you have
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
 [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
 // again add the date format what the output u need
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSString *finalDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"finalDate==%@",finalDate);
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: can i get zero timstamp date from this ?> means how to minus hours form time to get zero tmistamp.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your date format `@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` doesn't match your date string `@"2016-07-29 09:05"`. You need to use a different date format.

Working copy -
**Objective C**

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2016-07-29T09:05:00.00000Z";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

**Swift 2.x**

```
var dateformater = NSDateFormatter()
dateformater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
var dateString:String = "2016-07-29T09:05:00.00000Z"
let date:NSDate = dateformater.dateFromString(dateString)!

print(date)
```

Comment: but that's format i want... how do i c onvert into it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your formatterstyle as below

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2016-07-29 09:05";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

After that you can convert the date into below format :

```
dateFormat.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
NSString *str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: but i want this 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ' date format

Comment: @Kabali But the input string doesn't match that format.  So how would you expect that to work?

Comment: @Kabali you want the answer in which formate date or string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2016-07-29 09:05";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"the date  is %@",date);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSString *currentDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSDate *finaldate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDate];
NSLog(@"CurrentDate:%@", finaldate);
```