# Cannot assign a value of type 'NSDate' to a value of type 'String?'

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsdate

I am teaching myself swift and I am still very new but I decided to make a simple app that prints the current time when you press a button. the code from the viewcontroller file is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var LblTime: UILabel!
    @IBAction func BtnCalltime(sender: AnyObject) {
            var time = NSDate()
            var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM"
            var formatteddate = formatter.stringFromDate(time)
            LblTime.text = time
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

I am having an issue with the line:

```
LblTime.text = time
```

I keep getting the error:

> Cannot assign a value of type 'NSDate' to a value of type 'String?'

I have tried using:

```
lblTime.text = time as! string?
```

And:

```
lblTime.text = time as! string
```

but it does still not work, I would be very appreciative of some help.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288371/how-to-convert-string-to-nsdate-in-iphone this will help you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need use a value from formatter.

```
@IBAction func BtnCalltime(sender: AnyObject) {
    var time = NSDate()
    var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM"
    var formatteddate = formatter.stringFromDate(time)
    LblTime.text = formatteddate
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You made the string from an NSDate already, you just aren't using it.

```
lblTime.text = formatteddate
```

Answer (score 0):

Date is now preferred over NSDate. It is an overlay class meaning both will work, but Date but has a lot of advantages, [this answer lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811352/swift-3-date-vs-nsdate) some of those.

Here is how to format a date to a string using Date instead of NSDate.

```
var time = Date()
var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d yyyy, h:mm:ss a"
let formattedDateInString = formatter.string(from: time)

dateLabel.text = formattedDateInString
```

A great site to get the formatter strings is http://nsdateformatter.com/
I had no idea that `"MMM d yyyy, h:mm:ss a"` would equal `Mar 1, 7:02:35 AM` but the site makes it easy.