# how to use a static method in objective-c defined in extension

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3, swift-extensions

I have a static method created on extension of Date. I am trying to call this method in Objective-C file. I am getting error as "No Known class for selector method name".

More detail:

In SWIFT 3.0

```
extension Date {
     static func  getDefaultFormattedDateStringFromDate(_ validToDate:Date) -> String? {

    }
}
```

In Objective-C

```
NSString *dateString = [NSDate getDefaultFormattedDateTimeStringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 2):

`struct Date` is the "Swift overlay type" to the Foundation type 
`NSDate` (compare [Swift 3: Date vs NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811352/swift-3-date-vs-nsdate/39811401#39811401)) and unknown to Objective-C.

You'll have to define an extension to `NSDate` in order
to be useable from Objective-C:

```
extension NSDate {
    static func  getDefaultFormattedDateStringFromDate(_ validToDate: Date) -> String? {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is imported to Objective-C as

```
 @interface NSDate
 + (NSString * _Nullable)getDefaultFormattedDateStringFromDate:(NSDate * _Nonnull)validToDate;
 @end
```

Note that the parameter and return types (`Date`, `String`) are automatically bridged to the Foundation types (`NSDate`, `NSString`).

---

All this is unrelated to static (type) vs instance methods, and in
your case it might be more "natural" to define an instance
method:

```
extension NSDate {
    func defaultFormattedString() -> String? {
        // ...
    }
}
```

which is imported to Objective-C as

```
@interface NSDate
- (NSString * _Nullable)defaultFormattedString;
@end
```

and called as

```
NSString *dateString = [[NSDate date] defaultFormattedString];
```