# How to fix 'Cannot assign value of type 'NSDate' to type 'Date?'

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift4, nsdate

I am a beginner with swift and I'm trying to complete my first app. 
While I was typing the code, it showed me this:

> Cannot assign value of type 'NSDate' to type 'Date?

at

```
newBirthday.birthdate = birthdate as NSDate
```

I tried writing statements for making that line of code work but it wouldn't. Every time now I am running it, I would  get 6 errors.

```
let newBirthday = Birthday(context: context)
newBirthday.firstName = firstName
newBirthday.lastName = lastName
newBirthday.birthdayGift = birthdayGift
newBirthday.birthdate = birthdate as NSDate
newBirthday.birthdayID = UUID().uuidString
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `as NSDate`?

Comment: `birthdate` is a Date object or String value?

Comment: Show your `Birthday`'s structure. I think you have assigned `Date` type to `birthdate`.

Comment: I think you will get something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811352/swift-3-date-vs-nsdate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Swift 3, it no longer used Objective-c libraries NS

So if use Swift 3.0 or greater, then remove NS Prefix

In your case Birthday Object variable 'birthdate' is `Date` type not `NSDate`

if you can not assign `NSDate` in the `Date` object, for assign `NSDate` in `Date` you have cast first in `Date`.

```
newBirthday.birthdate = birthdate
```

Comment: Why would you use `as! Date` if the thing is already a `Date`? Just say `newBirthday.birthdate = birthdate` and be done with it.

Comment: "Cannot assign a value of type 'NSDate' to type 'Date?" 

I mean to say that variable cast according to error