# How to get show date as yesterday,today,2hours in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsdate

I am getting datetime from server as json response.Now if the date is equal to today date then i want to show it as today.if it was yesterday date then i want show as yesterday.if the time was 2 hours ago then i want to show as 2 hours.Please tell me how can implement such functionality?

Comment: Using this library :- https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo

Comment: Yes, You need to some changes as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

in .h file :

```
  NSDateFormatter *commonDateFormatter;
```

in .m file :

```
-(NSString*)convertToUTCTime:(NSString*)strDate{

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    myDate = [commonDateFormatter dateFromString: strDate];
    NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:myDate];
    return [self stringFromTimeInterval:distanceBetweenDates];
}
- (NSString *)stringFromTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
    NSInteger ti = (NSInteger)interval;
    NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
    NSInteger hours = (ti / 3600);

    if (hours > 24) {
        NSInteger days = hours/24;
        if (days > 30) {
           NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
           [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE d MMM, h:mm a"];
           //[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"IST"]];
            NSString *daydate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
            return daydate;
        }
        else{
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %2ldd",(long)days];
        }
    }else{
        if (hours == 0 && minutes < 1) {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Today"];
        }
        else if (hours == 0 && minutes < 60){
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2ldm ",(long)minutes];
        }
        else{
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %2ldh",(long)hours];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if there are more than weeks the how i return only th exact date

Comment: I can not understand what you trying to say

Comment: i want to ask what if there are too many days from current days then i want to print the date only.

Comment: my date format is this as string 2015-10-06 12:44:27

Comment: if you want display only date then change format of date  from [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE d MMM, h:mm a"]  to  [dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd"]

Comment: I don't understand this code.  How can `hours == 0 && minutes < 1 == "Today"`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert JSON to NSDate using NSDateFormatter [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288371/how-to-convert-string-to-nsdate-in-iphone)
2. Get current date
3. Get components between two days for month, week, day, hour interval unit using calendar components: fromDate: toDate: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates)
4. Compare two days for it is present or past [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112075/ios-compare-two-dates)
5. Then show component.month .day .hour past/future from current date