# How to convert a String to NSdate?

Tags: swift

I am trying to convert `fajerTime` to `NSDate`. When I compile the project the `dateValue` is `nil`. Any idea how to fix this issue?

```
if prayerCommingFromAdan.id == 0 && prayerCommingFromAdan.ringToneId != 0{
    //   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.methodOfReceivedNotification(_:)), name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)

    let fajerTime = "\(prayer0.time[0...1]):\(prayer0.time[3...4])" as String
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

    // convert string into date
    let dateValue = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fajerTime) as NSDate!
    print(dateValue)

    var dateComparisionResult:NSComparisonResult = NSDate().compare(dateValue)

    if dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
        addNotificationAlarm(year, month: month, day: day, hour: prayer0.time[0...1], minutes: prayer0.time[3...4], soundId: prayerCommingFromAdan.ringToneId, notificationBody: "It is al fajr adan")                    
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to NSDate in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288371/how-to-convert-string-to-nsdate-in-iphone)

Comment: Show content of `fajerTime`

Comment: The problem might be the format of `fajerTime`. It looks like `fajerTime` is a time string, e.g. `12:34`, whereas the date formatter is configured to accept string containing a month, day and year, e.g. `24-07-2016`.  You either need to format `fajerTime` according to the `MM-dd-yyyy` format, or otherwise configure the date formatter to accept a time, e.g. `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"`.

Comment: `fajerTime` seems to be just a time (h:m). Where do get the date (day, month, year) from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems be the format of `fajerTime`. It looks like `fajerTime` is a time string, e.g. `12:34`, whereas the date formatter is configured to accept string containing a month, day and year, e.g. `24-07-2016`.

You need to format `fajerTime` to include the year, month and day, as well as the time. Also configure the date formatter to accept the full date and time.

Assuming `prayer0` is an array, you will also need to combine the elements into a string, using `joinWithSeparator`.

e.g.

```
let hours = prayer0.time[0...1].joinWithSeparator("")
let minutes = prayer0.time[3...4].joinWithSeparator("")
let fajerTime = "\(month)-\(day)-\(year) \(hours):\(minutes)"
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

// convert string into date
let dateValue = dateFormatter.dateFromString(fajerTime) as NSDate!
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow example (**Swift 3**):

```
let dateStr = "2016-01-15 20:10:01 +0000"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
```

Keep in mind:

- Date format e.g. "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" must match the date string pattern
- In your case, your date string contains only time, yet, your date
  formatter contains only date
- When using dateFormatter.date() there is no need to cast it to Date as it returns a Date:
  [image]

Helpful website for date formats:

- http://nsdateformatter.com/